# Forcing Terraform to use particular region for data collection

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Currently working on a project in AWS China using AWS Organizations. According to AWS Support, the Organizations endpoints only exist in cn-northwest-1 however we are deploying to cn-north-1.

I am trying to pull a datasource in ([aws_organizations_organization](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/organizations_organization)).

I have set up the following AWS providers:

```html
provider "aws" {
  version = "3.4.0"
  region  = "cn-north-1"
}

provider "aws" {
  version = "3.4.0"
  region  = "cn-northwest-1"
  alias   = "northwest"
}
```

And I am pulling the data like so:

```html
data "aws_organizations_organization" "org" {
    provider      = aws.northwest
}
```

```html
Error: error listing AWS Service Access for Organization (redacted): UnsupportedAPIEndpointException: This API endpoint is not supported in this region
```

Any ideas? I kinda need this for my top level OU parent_id

```html
resource "aws_organizations_organizational_unit" "core" {
  name      = "core"
  parent_id = data.aws_organizations_organization.org.roots.0.id
}
```

Comment: Are you stating that it doesn't work at all or only in northwest?

Comment: It does not work at all, even pinned to northwest

Comment: Can you share the plan and/or the apply output  (redact what is needed)?